# Looping Through Temporal Dataset

Tags: python, gis, arcpy

I have a point feature class that includes columns with temporal data. How would I go about collecting the mean center of the first 10 years of data, then the first 20, first 30, etc... and exporting the results as points using a Python loop? I would like to measure the population shift of the data over time without have to manually calculate the effect of each decade.

I apologize if this is a naive question as I am just getting into programming.

The link below contains a file geodatabase that includes the feature class I'm working with.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw8dHpiUsYU7QjlKQnRSaDV5RnM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with something like this.

```
import os
import arcpy

in_feature = "C:\\temp\\mlb_birth.gdb\\mlb_birthplaces"
out_features = "C:\\temp\\mlb_birth.gdb"

for x in range(10, 140, 10):
    year_range = int(1870 + x)

    year_out_name = os.path.join(out_features, "Years_{0}".format(x))
    mean_out_name = os.path.join(out_features, "Mean_{0}".format(x))

    arcpy.Select_analysis(in_feature, year_out_name, "birthYear <= {0}".format(year_range))

    arcpy.MeanCenter_stats(year_out_name, mean_out_name, "#", "#", "#")
```